# Angual material Dialog with List Zero index not working with newer vesion

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-ng-click

Currently,I am facing one problem ,code is working in Angular 1.3 and material 0.6 version but not with newer version.

[Angular Material Model working `plunker` link](http://plnkr.co/edit/BitwOs71AtKv9hC8TXZt?p=preview)

**UPDATE:** Issue is replicated in below plunker

[Not Working with Angular 1.4.0 and Material 0.11.1](http://plnkr.co/edit/lnJhBC?p=preview)

At my localhost ,After Selecting English language instead of index alert box shows true [image: showing true instead of index]
[image: Blank language]

Comment: Code is identity, including order of import dependencies file

Comment: Hey ,thank you bringing attention.Now this issue is replicated http://plnkr.co/edit/lnJhBC?p=preview . in Previous plunkr used older versions